# 3d gravity and Chern-Simons: where does the $i$ come from?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-gravity, action, chern-simons-theory

According to @NiharKarve, in this stack-exchange post: [Regarding a possible duality between (2+1)D gravity and Chern-Simons Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/641131/), there is the relation:
\begin{equation}
S_\text{EH} \simeq \frac{\ell}{16\pi G} \int_\mathcal{M} \text{Tr}(I_\text{CS}[\textbf{A}_+]-I_\text{CS}[\textbf{A}_-])\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where $\simeq$ means we omit the boundary term, $\ell$ is the square root of the cosmological constant, and $I_\text{CS}[\textbf{A}_\pm]$ is the Chern-Simons 3-form of the gauge field $A_\pm^a = \omega^a\pm\ell^{-1}e^a$ (for $\omega$ the spin connection and $e$ the triad).

My problem comes from the equation $(\text{A}.33)$ of the article https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0210089, where it is stated that:
\begin{equation}
S_\text{CS}[A_+]-S_\text{CS}[A_-] = \mp 2i \left( S_\text{EH}[e,\omega] \mp \frac{1}{2}\oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}} e\wedge \omega \right)\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Though I have read the article quickly, I can't find where the $i$ factor comes from... Moreover right under $(3.10)$ it is said that in the formula
\begin{equation}
\Psi^{\pm}[B] = \int D[A]D[\bar{A}]\,e^{is S_\text{tot}^\pm[A,\bar{A}]},\tag{3}
\end{equation}
" *$s$ is real in the Euclidean signature and imaginary in the Lorentzian signature* ". This deepens my questioning regarding the appearance of the $i$ factor in $(2)$.

So my question is: Where does the $i$ factor come from in the article?

---

**EDIT**

I think I figured out what happens in the arXiv article I linked: the equation $(\text{A}.33)$ is only written for a cosmological constant $-\lambda <0$. This document: https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/f.a.bais/scripties/wemmenhoven.pdf (*Quantisation of 2+1 dimensional Gravity as a Chern-Simons theory* by Bastian Wemmenhove) eqs $(39)$ and $(51)$ helped me. So in Nihar's post, we have $\lambda = -\frac{1}{\ell^2}$, as usually defined. To conclude: I was just confused by all the convention changes in the arXiv article...

Comment: Are you referring to the $i$ in the exponential function?

Comment: @aygx No I am referring to the $i$ in $(2)$. I am ok with $i$ in the exponential function, except that manifestly, the Euclidean and Lorentzian cases are switched, and I think this is related to the former $i$.